# problems in Android Time-picker

Tags: android, time, datetimepicker, timepicker

I got a strange problem in android time picker control, when I trying to select 12PM it is returning the value like 12AM I tried in number of ways but I was unable to fix the problem and it is working fine for the other hours like 1,2, etc.

Code snippet as follows -

```
 case TIME_DIALOG_ID:

        // Time picker dialog generation
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                mhour = hourOfDay;
                mminute = minute;
                updatetime();
            }

        };

        return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, mhour, mminute,
                false);
```

Taking the hours and minutes value from time-picker I shows it into textView as follows -

```
public void updatetime() {
    textShowTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(mhour)).append(":")
            .append(pad(mminute)));
} 

private static String pad(int c) {
    if (c >= 10)
        return String.valueOf(c);
    else
        return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
}
```

And lastly I parse the textView value to getting the milliseconds......
But problem as described above are occur.

please help me where I do mistake or suggest any another solution for it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your code? and check if the time is in 24 hours format